# Java print a pattern with nested for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

I am struggling to build an algorithm that would print the much needed pattern. 
The code is the following:

```
public static void printPatternH(int size)
{
    for (int row = 1; row <= size; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 1; col <= 2*size; col++)
        {
            if (col > size + row - 1) {
                continue;
            }
            if (col <= size) {
                System.out.print((row + col >= size + 1 ? (row + col)%size : " ") + " ");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print((row + col >= size + 1 ? (row + size)%col : " ") + " ");
            }                
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The result is:
[image]

I understand that if `size` is 9 the last number in the middle will be 0 as `(row + size)%col = 0`, however I couldn't figure out a way to modify it without changing the rest of the values.

Comment: so you want to print "9" instead of "0" ?

Comment: `(row + col)%size` -> `(row + col - 1) % size + 1`

Comment: @saka1029, this can be the answer. care to post it :)

Comment: @AgelKoh yes, exactly, the solution from saka1029 fulfilled my query :) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
(row + col)%size
```

to

```
(row + col - 1) % size + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the "0" and replace it before printing it out:

```
 if (col <= size) {
     //print left hand side
     int remainder =  (row + col) % size;
     if (remainder == 0) remainder = size; //replace the "0" with size here.
     System.out.print((row + col >= size + 1 ? remainder : " ") + " ");
} else {
     //print right hand side
     System.out.print((row + col >= size + 1 ? (row + size) % col : " ") + " ");
}
```

It will give this output:

```
                1 
              1 2 1 
            1 2 3 2 1 
          1 2 3 4 3 2 1 
        1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 
      1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Testb 
{
    int item = 9;
    int limit = 5;
    int half = item/2;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //System.out.println("Hello World!");
        for(int i=0;i<limit;i++){
          
           for(int j=0;j<half;j++){
              
              if(j<(half-i)){
               
                 print(" ");
               
              }else{
              
                 print(j-(half-i))
              
              }          
           }
           
           print(i);

           for(int k=half;k<(half+i);k++){
           
               print((half+i)-(k+1));
           
           }

           println();
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
          0
        0 1 0
      0 1 2 1 0
    0 1 2 3 2 1 0
  0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 int rowCount = 1;

    System.out.println("Here Is Your Pyramid");

    //Implementing the logic

    for (int i = noOfRows; i > 0; i--)
    {
        //Printing i*2 spaces at the beginning of each row

        for (int j = 1; j <= i*2; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        //Printing j value where j value will be from 1 to rowCount

        for (int j = 1; j <= rowCount; j++)             
        {
            System.out.print(j+" ");
        }

        //Printing j value where j value will be from rowCount-1 to 1
         
        for (int j = rowCount-1; j >= 1; j--)
        {                 
            System.out.print(j+" ");             
        }                          
         
        System.out.println();

        //Incrementing the rowCount

        rowCount++;
    }
```

Comment: He does not ask a fully way different of his one, but to fix his one, he won't learn it he just use another way.